# Java Threading Unexpected Behavior

Tags: java, multithreading

We have been looking at a threading error for a while and are not sure how this is possible. Below is a minimized example from our code. There is a cache holding data retrieved from a database (or: "a lengthy synchronous operation", as far as this example is concerned). There is a thread for reloading the cache, while other threads try to query the cache. There is a period of time when the cache is null, waiting to be reloaded. It should not be queryable during this time, and we tried to enforce this by synchronizing the methods that access the cache - both for reading and writing. Yet if you run this class for a while, you will get NPEs in `search()`. How is this possible?

Java docs state that "it is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the same object to interleave. When one thread is executing a synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first thread is done with the object".

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class CacheMultithreading01 {
    private long dt = 1000L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CacheMultithreading01 cm = new CacheMultithreading01();
        cm.demonstrateProblem();
    }

    void demonstrateProblem() {
        QueryableCache cache = new QueryableCache();
        runInLoop("Reload", new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                cache.reload();
            }
        });
        runInLoop("Search", new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                cache.search(2);
            }
        });
        // If the third "runInLoop" is commented out, no NPEs
        runInLoop("_Clear", new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                cache.clear();
            }
        });
    }

    void runInLoop(String threadName, Runnable r) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public synchronized void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        r.run();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        log("Error");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, threadName).start();
    }

    void log(String s) {
        System.out.format("%d %s %s\n", System.currentTimeMillis(), Thread
                .currentThread().getName(), s);
    }

    class QueryableCache {
        private List<Integer> cache = new ArrayList<>();

        public synchronized void reload() {
            clear();
            slowOp(); // simulate retrieval from database
            cache = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
        }

        public synchronized void clear() {
            cache = null;
        }

        public synchronized Integer search(Integer element) {
            if (cache.contains(element))
                return element;
            else
                return null;
        }

        private void slowOp() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(dt);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
//java.lang.NullPointerException
//at examples.multithreading.cache.CacheMultithreading01$QueryableCache.search(CacheMultithreading01.java:73)
//at examples.multithreading.cache.CacheMultithreading01$2.run(CacheMultithreading01.java:26)
//at examples.multithreading.cache.CacheMultithreading01$4.run(CacheMultithreading01.java:44)
//at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

We do not understand why the NPEs can happen even though the code is synchronized. We also do not understand why the NPEs stop happening if we comment out the third call to `runInLoop` (the one that does `cache.clear`).
We have also tried to implement locking using a `ReentrantReadWriteLock` - and the result is the same.

Comment: So in this code there is no synchronization on the cache object. So does the QueryableCache do synchronization? Can you post that code? The NPE seems like it's on some internal data structure to QueryableCache.

Comment: Does/should slowOp() return something? I doesn't do anything here.

Comment: The posted code is self-sufficient. It runs and throws NPEs. All methods of QueryableCache are synchronized (on the intrinsic lock of the instance of QueryableCache, of which there is only one). You can play with the code, e.g. add a private member to QueryableCache and synchronize on that. In our tests, same result.

Comment: "The posted code is self-sufficient" It is not. Post an SSCCE.

Comment: @WillD it simulates DB retrieval - which our real code does have - and it keeps the `cache` null for a longer time, increasing the likelihood that `search` will try to query the cache. Don't want to keep you waiting

Comment: @m0skit0 Did you try running it? It is a Java class that can be run as posted (no dependencies). What error did you get?

Comment: @m0skit0 What is an SSCE? I only know [mcve]

Comment: Oh wow, my bad. I totally missed the scroll on the code block. Sorry.

Comment: Have you considered just using Guava's caches instead of implementing your own? [Guava Caches Explained](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained)

Comment: @GhostCat It is basically the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synchronization is working as correctly.

The problem is that the method `clear` puts cache to `null`. And there is no guarantee that `reload` method will be called before `search`.

Also, note that the method `reload`, it's not releasing the lock. So, when you are waiting for the `slowOp` to finish, the other methods can't execute.

Answer (score 3):

You have to check in the `search` method if `cache` is null. Otherwise calling `contains` on it in `search` can throw a `NullPointerException` in the case that you  have previously set `cache` to null in the `clear`-method.

Comment: But since the methods are synchronized, it should not be possible for another thread to enter `search()` while `reload()` is executing. Is this not the guarantee of synchronization?

Comment: you are expecting the methods to execute in the right order. But that is not ensured, you should then do a reload in the same synchronized method as clear.

Comment: @radumanolescu That is not the problem here. A call to `clear` can be directly followed by a consecutive call to `search`. By the synchronization mechanics that you are currently applying, it is not guaranteed that there happens a call to `reload` in between.

Comment: Remember too that in this implementation, clear() is public. You have no control over who calls it when. You may want to search your code for accesses outside of **QueryableCache**

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't have any more advanced locking, you can call `clear()` and `search()` consecutively. That will obviously cause a NPE.

Calling `reload()` and `search()` won't cause problems, since in reload the cache is cleared, then rebuilt, inside a synchronized block, preventing other (search) operations from being executed in between.

Why is there a `clear()` method that will leave `cache` in a "bad" state (which `search()` doesn't even check for)?

Comment: You have put me on the right track. We have a separate "clear" method here because this is how it is in the real production code. I though that the NPE would occur while `reload` is running - but it can actually easily occur if you run `clear` then `search` then `reload`

Comment: Adding more advanced locking has not helped, as I mentioned. It's simply an issue of sequencing (`clear` then `search`).

Answer (score 2):

"There is a period of time when the cache is null, waiting to be reloaded."
This is your problem: `clear` sets things to null, and then returns, releasing the synchronization lock, allowing someone else to access.
It would be better to make the "new" assignment atomic and not `clear()`.

Assuming that slowOp() needs to return data for the cache (`private List<Integer> slowOp())` you retrieve that data before assigning it

`ArrayList<Integer> waitingForData = slowOp();
cache = watingForData;`

This 'updates' the cache only after the data is available. Assignment is an atomic operation, nothing can access **cache** while the reference is being updated.

Answer (score 1):

Three different threads invoking clear() search() and reload() of the cache without a definitive interleaving. Since the interleaving doesn't gurantees the the sequence of lock being obtained for the clear() and search() threads there could be chances where the search thread is getting the lock over the object just after the clear() thread. In that case the search would result in the NullPointerException.

You may have to check for the cache equal to null in the search object and may be do a reload() from within the search() method. This would gurantee the search result or return null as applicable.